# DOM modifications to popup or tab in chrome extension instantly undone once script completes

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome-extension

When clicking the BrowserAction, `test.html` opens in a new tab.  This works as expected.  Here is `background.js`:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function () {
  chrome.tabs.create({
    url: "./test.html"
  });
});
```

Here is `test.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
  <form>
   <fieldset id="top">
    <button id="clickme">click me</button>
   </fieldset>
   <fieldset id="bottom">
   </fieldset>
  </form>
  <script src="test.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

`test.html` invokes `test.js`:

```
console.log("checking in");

document.getElementById("clickme").onclick = function () {
 var newButton = document.createElement("button");
 newButton.textContent = "now click me";
 newButton.onclick = function () {
  document.getElementById("bottom").style.backgroundColor = "pink";
 };
 document.getElementById("bottom").appendChild(newButton);
 alert("I'm an alert. If you comment me out, the tab will revert to its unmodified state, probably before you even see the second button.");
};
```

The new button appears, but disappears once the alert is cleared.  I find that DOM modifications made to tabs or popups opened in an extension always revert to their original state as soon as the script completes.  Is there a way to get one of these to hold still?

Comment: Your html has no closing tag for `<fieldset id="bottom">`, missing `/` in the subsequent `<fieldset>`. There could be something else in your code that "undoes" the changes. Chrome only recreates the toolbar button popup (and page action popup) each time the button is clicked.

Comment: Thanks.  Corrected that.  The behavior is unchanged.

Comment: Put a copy in https://github.com/n8chz/chrome-tab-demo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `<form>` gets resubmitted on click and in the absence of action url it simply reloads the page.

Either don't use `<form>` at all or use a proper onsubmit event listener or add `event.preventDefault();` in *all* your click listeners or add `type="button"` to all your buttons.

Comment: Or simply button with `type = "button"` (it's `"submit"` by default)